# PyQT5 live updating plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt5, traceback

I need help with adding live plotting to each of these graphs. I tried many solutions but every single one kept crashing my window. Is there a simple fix that I'm missing?

Down below is code without any updating method:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.button5 = QPushButton('Lane 5')
        self.button4 = QPushButton('Lane 4')
        self.button3 = QPushButton('Lane 3')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Lane 2')
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Lane 1')

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.plot2)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.plot3)
        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.plot4)
        self.button5.clicked.connect(self.plot5)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button3)
        layout.addWidget(self.button4)
        layout.addWidget(self.button5)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot1(self):
        data = pd.read_csv("2021-08-13.csv", parse_dates=['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
        datafilter = data[data.lane == "Lane 1 Op2"]
        datafilter['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafiltr['time'], errors='coerce')
        df = datafilter['time'].groupby(datafilter.godzina.dt.to_period("H")).agg('count')
        y = [df.index[i].to_timestamp() for i in range(len(df))]
        self.figure.clear()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.bar(y, df, width=0.035)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is csv file sample:

```
lane,detail,time,potentiometer,piece,tooltime
Lane 3 Op3,3584,00:00:03,100%,873,0:00:58
Lane 3 Op2,00:00:20,150,,,
Lane 4 Op3,00:01:40,811,,,
Lane 3 Op1,1584,00:00:20,100%,149,0:01:32
Lane 2 Op2,2508,00:00:40,110%,151,0:01:49
Lane 3 Op1,00:00:34,149,,,
Lane 2 Op3,3508,00:00:56,100%,551,0:01:05
Lane 2 Op2,00:00:25,151,,,
Lane 3 Op3,00:01:07,873,,,
Lane 4 Op2,2858,00:01:31,100%,104,0:02:34
Lane 4 Op3,3858,00:01:32,100%,812,0:01:20
Lane 2 Op1,1508,00:01:33,100%,152,0:01:35
Lane 1 Op1,1141,00:01:38,100%,125,0:01:49
Lane 1 Op2,1141,00:01:38,100%,125,0:01:49
Lane 3 Op2,2584,00:01:51,100%,151,0:01:45
```

Comment: Please, can you provide a sample of your data saved in `2021-08-13.csv`?

Comment: Lane 5 Op2,2995,00:47:35,100%,18,1:19:29
I'm using only time (00:47:35 in this example) for now

Comment: I have issue with the data, since in your code there is a reference to `datafilter.godzina` which isn't in the data you provided. What is `godzina`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The csv file was made in polish so I had to use some polish names earlier. godzina means hour, just change it to time.

Comment: @Jukel what is the error message? open CMD/console and execute `python /path/of/script.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code. I suggest you to add this to your code:

```
import traceback

def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print("".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)))
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = handle_exception
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it this way, each error which will crash your window will be printed, so you can see what is going on.

---

The first error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main = Window()
  File "C:/Users/main.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.button2.clicked.connect(self.plot2)
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'plot2'
```

In the `__init__` method you connect some signal to not defined functions `self.plot2`, `self.plot3` and so on.

---

If I comment those line, then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/main.py", line 44, in plot1
    datafilter['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafiltr['time'], errors='coerce')
NameError: name 'datafiltr' is not defined
```

this is a typo in `datafilter`.

---

Fixed this typo, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/main.py", line 45, in plot1
    df = datafilter['time'].groupby(datafilter.godzina.dt.to_period("H")).agg('count')
  File "C:\Users\VENV\stack\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5141, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'godzina'
```

This is do to a translation problem, as you already pointed out: `godzina` --> `time`.

---

Finally, fixed all those issues, I get the working window:

[image]

**Working code**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import traceback


class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.button5 = QPushButton('Lane 5')
        self.button4 = QPushButton('Lane 4')
        self.button3 = QPushButton('Lane 3')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Lane 2')
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Lane 1')

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot1)
        # self.button2.clicked.connect(self.plot2)
        # self.button3.clicked.connect(self.plot3)
        # self.button4.clicked.connect(self.plot4)
        # self.button5.clicked.connect(self.plot5)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button3)
        layout.addWidget(self.button4)
        layout.addWidget(self.button5)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot1(self):
        data = pd.read_csv("2021-08-13.csv", parse_dates=['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
        datafilter = data[data.lane == "Lane 1 Op2"]
        datafilter['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafilter['time'], errors='coerce')
        df = datafilter['time'].groupby(datafilter.time.dt.to_period("H")).agg('count')
        y = [df.index[i].to_timestamp() for i in range(len(df))]
        self.figure.clear()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.bar(y, df, width=0.035)
        self.canvas.draw()

def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print("".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)))
    sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = handle_exception
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

However I get the warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  datafilter['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafilter['time'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, with traceback it's gonna be so much easier. I hope I can figure this out by myself now. Have a good day:)

Comment: Note that while Qt sometimes throws "silent" errors, and IDEs often don't provide complete feedback, most problems can be traced just by running your code in a terminal/prompt, without requiring the exception handler.